# AudioContext createMediaElementSource from video fetching data from blob

Tags: javascript, html, audiocontext

In javascript, How can I connect an audio context to a video fetching its data from a blob (the video uses the MediaStream capabilities). No matter what I do the audio context returns an empty buffer. Is there any way to connect the two?

Comment: facing the same problem for a long while. Did you manage to find a solution? it would help me greatly.

Comment: nope, i ended up doing it through the server

Answer (score 3):

Probably, `createMediaElementSource` is not the right kind of processing `node` for this use-case.
Rather, you better off to use *[createMediaStreamSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource)* node from WebAudio API in case you are trying to handle audio live stream, not fixed media source.

> The `createMediaStreamSource()` method of the `AudioContext` Interface is used to create a new `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` object, given a media stream (say, from a `navigator.getUserMedia` instance), the audio from which can then be played and manipulated.

The link has a more detailed example. However, the main difference for this `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` is it can be created **only** using a *[MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream)* that you get from media-server or locally(through `getUserMedia`). In my experience, i couldn't find any way by using only the `blob` url from the `<video>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

While this is an old question, I've searched for something similar and found a solution I want to share.

To connect the Blob, you may use a new Response instance. Here is an example for creating a wave form visualizer.

```
var audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
var dataArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    
var arrayBuffer = await new Response(yourBlob).arrayBuffer();
var audioBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
var source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = audioBuffer;
source.connect(analyser);
source.start(0);
```

Note: `yourBlob` needs to be a Blob instance.

You may find [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kirschkern/xm9b5g4L/1/) usefull which records video and audio for 5 seconds, turns the recording into a Blob and than plays it back including audio wave visualization.